# Rails 3 default routes with controllers in custom directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to create a default route for my application:

```
match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

The thing is that my controllers are located in different folders, like this:

```
/myapp/app/controller/admin/base_controller.rb
```

However, Rails doesn't seem to recognize these controllers with my default route, it does recognize a controller if it is in 'myapp/app/controller/some_controller.rb' though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to add a namespace for each of your directories, containing the default route within:

```
namespace :admin do
  match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
end

namespace :something_else do
  match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
end
```

You could probably do it programmatically by inspecting your directory structure, using the Dir and File classes. In either case, I'd advise against using default routes unless you have a strong reason to do so.